# JavaScript/Lodash - Keep unique elements only

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array that should contain only unique elements in it (elements that doesn't currently exists on the array) and only unique elements are supposed to be pushed into it.

The array :

```
  [{
          "group1": [{
                  "objectId": "lFIlRCwbgY"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "OjHJ1DlP04"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "Xasht4pMus"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "X3qEb8tBtA"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "group2": [{
                  "objectId": "rwyACF8j1u"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "al3Ko6cuUr"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "VqJMLDDs5W"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "gIjh41rI0i"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "group3": [{
                  "objectId": "X3qEb8tBtA"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "GRFIMzVxiL"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "gIjh41rI0i"
              },
              {
                  "objectId": "n6JI6cq7B6"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
```

Currently I am doing the following way to have unique IDs in each group:

```
     var restaurantFound = _.some(this.wholeGroup[0].group1, { objectId: el.objectId });

     if (this.wholeGroup[1]) {
      if (restaurantFound == false && this.wholeGroup[1].group2.length < 4) {
        this.wholeGroup[1].group2.push(el.objectId);
      }
    }
```

**Issue:**

In 10% of the times an element with an Id gets repeated, for example in the JSON above the element `gIjh41rI0i` in group 2 was repeated in group 3.

Comment: So, you want to have a group array of 4 elements of the unique object.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to accomplish ... could you provide a sample array with the you want to have?

Comment: @HassanImam yes

Comment: @MichelEngelen as I said already, I want to have unique ID's meaning if I have id `1` in `group1` that item with id `1` should never be repeated again in the whole array

Comment: @HamzaL. I guess the problem is that you check existence of a new id only  in `group1` - you should check it in all groups.

Comment: In addition to that: The provided structure makes it hard to perform checks on it automatically. I am currently writing a proposal with a slightly different array-structure ... stay tuned! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to work with your data structure but it seems I managed to perform checking and adding items automatically:

```js
var wholeGroup = [{
  "group1": [{
    "objectId": "lFIlRCwbgY"
  }, {
    "objectId": "OjHJ1DlP04"
  }, {
    "objectId": "Xasht4pMus"
  }, {
    "objectId": "X3qEb8tBtA"
  }]
}, {
  "group2": [{
    "objectId": "rwyACF8j1u"
  }, {
    "objectId": "al3Ko6cuUr"
  }, {
    "objectId": "VqJMLDDs5W"
  }, {
    "objectId": "gIjh41rI0i"
  }]
}, {
  "group3": [{
    "objectId": "X3qEb8tBtA"
  }, {
    "objectId": "GRFIMzVxiL"
  }, {
    "objectId": "gIjh41rI0i"
  }]
}];

var el = {
  objectId: "n6JI6cq7B4"
};
var el2 = {
  objectId: "n6JI6cq7B8"
};

tryAdd(wholeGroup, el);
tryAdd(wholeGroup, el);
tryAdd(wholeGroup, el2);

function tryAdd(wholeGroup, el){
  var list = _.map(wholeGroup, function(obj) { return _.values(obj); });

  var exist = _.some(_.flatten(list), { 'objectId': el.objectId });

  if (!exist) {
    var last = wholeGroup[wholeGroup.length - 1];
    var key = _.keys(last)[0];

    if (last[key].length < 4) {
      last[key].push(el);
      console.log("Add " + el.objectId + " to "+ key);
    } else {
      var number = +key[key.length - 1];
      var newGroup = {};
      var newKey = "group" + (number + 1);
      newGroup[newKey] = [el];
      wholeGroup.push(newGroup);
      console.log("Add " + el.objectId + " to new group "+ newKey);
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log(el.objectId + " already exists");
  }
}
console.log(wholeGroup);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.2.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Please notice that there are a lot of omitted null/index/exception checking.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I believe that does not answers my questions as what it outputs something really different and it made things more complicated

Comment: My `tryAdd` function adds an item to your array only if this item is not already presented. Also it's keeps groups size and automatically create new ones. So what is wrong? Which output do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all unique `objectId` by flattening and using `new Set()`. Then you can group your object in the group of 4 and then you can create result using `array#reduce`.

```js
var data = [{ "group1": [{ "objectId": "lFIlRCwbgY" }, { "objectId": "OjHJ1DlP04" }, { "objectId": "Xasht4pMus" }, { "objectId": "X3qEb8tBtA" } ] }, { "group2": [{ "objectId": "rwyACF8j1u" }, { "objectId": "al3Ko6cuUr" }, { "objectId": "VqJMLDDs5W" }, { "objectId":"gIjh41rI0i" } ] }, { "group3": [{ "objectId": "X3qEb8tBtA" }, { "objectId": "GRFIMzVxiL" }, { "objectId": "gIjh41rI0i" }, { "objectId": "n6JI6cq7B6" } ] } ],
  result = [...new Set([].concat(...data.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]))
      .map(o => Object.values(o)[0]))]
      .reduce((r,objectId,i) => {
        let index = Math.floor(i/4);
        r[index] = r[index] || [];
        r[index].push({objectId});
        return r;
      },[])
      .reduce((r,a,i) => {
        r.push({['group'+(i+1)] : a});
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the taken time and efforts but as I said in the question, I am looking for something in lodash just to avoid complications